# Load testing and Tsung - while start recording

Tags: tsung

I face this problem when I start recording or start tsung with command

```
1) sh tsung-recorder.sh start
2) sh tsung.sh start
--------error---------
tsung-recorder.sh: line 61: [: 5.7.5: unary operator expected
Starting Tsung recorder on port 8090
[root@aum44 tsung-1.4.2]# {"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','/usr/lib/erlang//lib/tsung_recorder-1.4.2/priv/tsung_recorder.boot'}}
--------error---------
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you do ./configure, and make to compile if all was ok you have now to install tsung, if not you won't be able to run tsung, if you want to run it from the directory where the sources are you have to edit tsung.sh to fix paths.